# How to use cycles to cut and paste a word through colums in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

First of all I'm sorry for my english. This is the problem --->

I need to see the "effect" in the sheet, like the word appears, disappears and appears again in the next columns (like moving). (5, 4) is where I write the word initially.

If you do it manually it looks like cut and paste from D5 to N5

The idea is to it with "For" (Cycles)

This is what i have done so far --- >

PD: (I'm newie) I started programming a couple of weeks ago

Thanks in advance

```
Sub ejem()
    For i = 5 To 14
    
        sug.Cells(5, i) = sug.Cells(5, 4)
        
        
        
    Next i
    
    For a = 6 To 15
    
        
        sug.Cells(a, 14) = sug.Cells(5, 4)
    
     Next a
     
 

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a little unclear between your text and your code exactly what it is you want to do.
The following takes a literal interpretation of your text.

This code goes to the top of the module

```
''' It's good practice to insist on variable declaration (saves a lot of debug effort)
    Option Explicit

''' Declare the Sleep function (so you can add delays)
    Private Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)
```

Your sub:

```
Sub ejem()
    
''' With Option Explicit, you need to declare your variables
''' (which you should get in the habit of)
    Dim i%, lgMS&, vnVal
    
''' Change this to increase/decrease the delay
    lgMS = 30

''' In order to 'see it', I assume the sheet is the active sheet
''' If not (e.g. you have multiple windows open, change this to whatever 'sug' was
    With ActiveSheet
        
        vnVal = .Cells(5, 4)
        
        .Cells(5, 5) = vnVal:           Sleep lgMS
        For i = 5 To 13
            .Cells(5, i).ClearContents: Sleep lgMS
            .Cells(5, i + 1) = vnVal:   Sleep lgMS
        Next i
        
        .Cells(5, 14).ClearContents:    Sleep lgMS
        .Cells(6, 14) = vnVal:          Sleep lgMS
        
        For i = 6 To 14
            .Cells(i, 14).ClearContents: Sleep lgMS
            .Cells(i + 1, 14) = vnVal:   Sleep lgMS
        Next i
    
    End With

End Sub
```

Additional information:
The Sleep declaration above is Private (as that allows it to go into any module). If you want to use it for other things, you can declare it as public in which case it must go to a 'standard' public module.